# Contents of PyString in Qt Creator debugger?

Tags: python, qt, debugging, qt-creator, cpython

I've got a PyString* object that I would like to see the contents of. Is there any way to see the text of the PyString using Qt Creator's debugger?

```
PyObject *import_str = PyString_InternFromString("__import__");
```

If it makes a difference, Qt Creator is a front end to GDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write debugging info to be displayed in QtCreator for any class using Python with the latest QtCreator.  It's actually quite simple. This is thanks to gdb 7 that added support for Python in addition to C++.

You can see the ones that ship with QtCreator in `/usr/share/qtcreator/gdbmacros`.
For more info you can check QtCreator documentation and [this blog post from Qt Labs](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/12/15/peek-and-poke-vol-2/).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that Qt Creator can display the contents of the string like it does with `QString`, etc.  This is because `PyObject` is a custom class that Qt Creator/gdbv does not know how to handle.

For instance: `QString` is a custom class as well, but Qt Creator loads some special commands/modules/whatever which allows for direct display of string values in the debugger.

I never did that myself, but I guess that there are ways to make gdb pass the correct information to Qt Creator.